# In R, is the any way can fill NA and keep variable attribute?

Tags: r, dataframe, fill, zoo

Using `zoo::na.fill(0)` can fill all the NA by 0 , but this will change the variable attribute,
for instance, the attribute of variable `amount` is `num` in dataframe md, after `zoo::na.fill(0)` the attribute  change to `chr`. Is the any way can fill na so easy like `na.fill` and keep variable attribute?

```
md <- data.frame(cat=c('a','b','d',NA,'E',NA),
                 subcat=c('A','C',NA,NA,NA,'D'),
                 amount=c(1,2,NA,5,NA,8)) 

md %>% zoo::na.fill(0)
```

[image: Data]

Comment: Why not just `mutate` and `zoo::na.fill` every column? Something like this `md %>% dplyr::mutate(across(.fns = zoo::na.fill, fill = 0L))`

Comment: Could you help to give specific code ? Thanks!

Comment: I did give you the code. Have you tried it?

Comment: thanks!  i tried ,it's ok.  .fns means all variables?

Comment: No, it means the function(s) applied to the variables selected. By default, `across` selects all variables. If you want to select a subset of variables, for instance, first 2, try `md %>% dplyr::mutate(across(1:2, .fns = zoo::na.fill, fill = 0L))`

Comment: Got it , thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution without the usage of zoo.

```
library(dplyr)
md2 <- md %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.factor), as.character)) %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.character), function(x) { replace(x, is.na(x), "0") } )) %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), function(x) { replace(x, is.na(x), 0) } )) %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.character), as.factor))
```

If you want to, you can wrap this into a self-defined function to use it as easily as the fill-na method by zoo, e.g.

```
FillNA <- function(df){
  df2 <- df %>% 
    mutate(across(where(is.factor), as.character)) %>% 
    mutate(across(where(is.character), function(x) { replace(x, is.na(x), "0") } )) %>% 
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), function(x) { replace(x, is.na(x), 0) } )) %>% 
    mutate(across(where(is.character), as.factor)) 
  return(df2)
}
```

Here the verification for the types:

```
> str(md)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ cat   : Factor w/ 4 levels "a","b","d","E": 1 2 3 NA 4 NA
 $ subcat: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","C","D": 1 2 NA NA NA 3
 $ amount: num  1 2 NA 5 NA 8

str(FillNA(md))
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ cat   : Factor w/ 5 levels "0","a","b","d",..: 2 3 4 1 5 1
 $ subcat: Factor w/ 4 levels "0","A","C","D": 2 3 1 1 1 4
 $ amount: num  1 2 0 5 0 8
```

Answer (score 0):

An update code , Just mark it

```
md %>% mutate(across(cat:amount,~ replace(.x,is.na(.x),0)))
```